# Primefaces Draggable Drop Position

Tags: jsf, primefaces, drag-and-drop

I need to get the drop position of a draggable panel. But i cannot figure out how to do it. I've tried to get the style but I've got unrelated information.

Here is my xhtml :

```
<h:form id="dnd">

   <p:panel id="draggable1" 
            style="z-index:1; width: 60px; height: 60px;">
       <h:outputText value="CAM-1" />
       <p:draggable for="draggable1" 
                    revert ="false"/>
   </p:panel>

   <p:panel id="droppable" 
            style="z-index:1; width: 600px; height: 600px;">
      <p:droppable for="droppable"> 
          <p:ajax listener="#{myBean.onDrop}" />
      </p:droppable>
   </p:panel>

</h:form>
```

Here is my backing bean :

```
public void onDrop(DragDropEvent dragDropEvent) {
    String dragId = dragDropEvent.getDragId();

    UIComponent draggedItem = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent(dragId);

    System.out.println(draggedItem.getClientId());
    Panel draggedPanel = (Panel) draggedItem;

    String style = draggedPanel.getStyle();
    System.out.println(style);

    String styleClass = draggedPanel.getStyleClass();
    System.out.println(styleClass);
}
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

PrimeFaces is using jQuery UI [`.droppable()`](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/b2c095571eb81ac9ff6dd3180630e7f6c4fad115/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/dragdrop/dragdrop.js#L36), to get the position you should alter the event binding in `PrimeFaces.widget.Droppable`, this is done in [`bindDropListener`](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/b2c095571eb81ac9ff6dd3180630e7f6c4fad115/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/dragdrop/dragdrop.js#L41).

Adding a couple of request params to the original request would do it, here's an example:

```
PrimeFaces.widget.Droppable.prototype.bindDropListener = function() {
   var _self = this;

   this.cfg.drop = function(event, ui) {
       if (_self.cfg.onDrop) {
           _self.cfg.onDrop.call(_self, event, ui);
       }
       if (_self.cfg.behaviors) {
           var dropBehavior = _self.cfg.behaviors['drop'];

           if (dropBehavior) {
               var ext = {
                    params: [
                       {name: _self.id + '_dragId', value: ui.draggable.attr('id')},
                       {name: _self.id + '_dropId', value: _self.cfg.target},
                       {name: ui.draggable.attr('id') + '_left', value: ui.position.left},
                       {name: ui.draggable.attr('id') + '_top', value: ui.position.top}
                    ]
                };

                dropBehavior.call(_self, ext);
           }
       }
    };
}
```

The change here is adding two more parameters to the `ext` params of the request, where the positions of the draggable item (left, top) are present.

On the other side of the event `onDrop(DragDropEvent dragDropEvent)`, you can find them as request parameters as I have mentioned.

```
public void onDrop(DragDropEvent dragDropEvent) {
    String dargId = dragDropEvent.getDragId();
    Map<String, String> params = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
    String left = params.get(dargId + "_left");
    String top = params.get(dargId + "_top");
}
```

Note: the ajax event should be present in `p:droppable` (as in the question)

You can find a small example on [github](https://github.com/hatemalimam/DailyLab/blob/master/src/main/webapp/panelDrag/main.xhtml), and a working [demo](http://jsf.hatemalimam.com/DailyLab/panelDrag/main.xhtml).